# Changing url of one iframe from another

Tags: javascript, html, url, iframe

I have a page with 2 iframe tags:

```
<iframe src="top.html" seamless="seamless" width=100% height=100% id="up" name="up" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe src="main.html" seamless="seamless" width=100% height=800px id="main" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Inside main.html I have the following code:

```
parent.frames['up'].location.href = "top.html";
```

The idea is to refresh the "up" iframe.
Sometimes it's working, sometimes nothing happens, and sometimes I get an exception:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
The problem happens when loading the page by double clicking it. The domain of both the iframe and it's parent must be the same. When loading the file by double clicking it, they are both with the domain "null", and because (null===null) return false, an exception is raised.
To make this code work I had to run it from a web server.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
parent.frames["up"].location.replace("top.html")
```